# Quit error Internet Explorer Window

Tags: windows, vba, internet-explorer

**Issue :** I am currently encountering some issues closing a "premature" internet window which has no content yet.

[image: prematured window]

Basically if this "premature" window is open, my macro doesn't manage to select the window I'm interested in, but as soon as I close this "premature" window manually, I can run my code properly. 
Its source comes from a minor error which somehow opens it but except diplaying that window doesn't affect the rest of the code.

**Tests done :**

```
Dim Widow As Object, page_foireuse As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim objShell As Object
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

     MsgBox objShell.Windows.Count
'    MsgBox objShell.Windows(0).document.Title
'    MsgBox objShell.Windows(1).document.Title
'    MsgBox objShell.Windows(2).document.Title
'    MsgBox objShell.Windows(3).document.Title
'    MsgBox objShell.Windows(4).document.Title
'    MsgBox objShell.Windows(5).document.Title
'    MsgBox objShell.Windows(6).document.Title


'For Each Widow In objShell.Windows
'    If Widow.document.Title Is Nothing Then ' this doesn't work
'        Set page_foireuse = Widow
'    End If
'Next

'
'If objShell.Windows(5).document.Title Is Nothing Then
'End If
        Set page_foireuse = objShell.Windows(5)
    page_foireuse.Quit

 MsgBox objShell.Windows.Count
```

**Results so far :**

1. When I count the number of windows in the shell, this "premature" window is also counted
2. When I return the location or title of each of the counted windows, I get an error when trying to return the location or title of the "premature" window

   3. The two loops I tried to run at this end didn't work

So my question is : How can I close this "premature" window via the macro ?

Comment: What error do you get and where (which line of code)?

Comment: When I try to msgBox the title of this page it doesn't work and the error description returns _Automation error , unspecified error_

Answer (score 1):

The page on the image in your question looks strange, no location, no title. Try the following code, but set breakpoint on the line `Set doc = ie.document` and check if `doc` is not `Nothing` etc. HTH

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library
' Add reference to Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation

Dim ie As SHDocVw.WebBrowser
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim shellApp As Shell32.Shell
Dim windows As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim window

Set shellApp = New Shell
Set windows = shellApp.windows

For Each window In windows
    If Not UCase(window.FullName) Like "*IEXPLORE.EXE" Then GoTo continue
    Set ie = window
    Set doc = ie.document
    If doc.Title = "" Then
        ie.Quit
        Exit For
    End If
continue:
Next window
```

Comment: I tried it. As you planned, it's on the `Set doc = ie.document` line that the code breaks when the "premature" window is the one we go through. The returned error is the same as I mentioned above. It's weird because this page can be counted so it is somehow recognized, but since no path has been linked ot it seems impossible to select it. Also in my test code, I can spot which window is the "premature" one, and then if I try to quit it, it actually quits the window following it in the count instead. `Set page_foireuse = objShell.Windows(5)
    page_foireuse.Quit`

Comment: OK, it's a shame, I managed to find the error and to avoid the opening on this "premature" webpage. Then closing it is still a mystery. Unfortunately, since this webpage is from an intranet it's hard to give you an accessible example to relate with, thanks for your support though !